# Semanticui sidebar icons hover do not show menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to replicate [this sidebar example](https://codepen.io/telatkaya/pen/dpPNWd) I have found in my rails application however, the hovering feature on icons to show the menu items does not work in my case.

I only did some minor tweaks to the code like moving some of the style to my CSS file and re-arranging the icons.

CSS for the sidebar

```
.displaynone {
  display: none !important;
}

.displayblock {
  display: block !important;
}

.sidebar .item i {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: -5px !important;
}

.logo {
  height: 48px !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 38px !important;
}

.title.item {
  padding: .92857143em 1.14285714em !important;
}

.dropdown .menu .header {
  padding-top: 3.9px!important;
  padding-bottom: 3.9px!important;
}

.ui.sidebar.vertical.menu {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  margin-top: 71px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

HTML for sidebar (in slim format)

```
.ui.sidebar.vertical.left.menu.overlay.visible
  .ui.accordion
    a.title.item
        | Dashboard
        i.dropdown.icon
    .content
        a.item Dashboard

    .title.item
      i.dropdown.icon 
      | Apps
    .content
      a.item Inbox
      a.item Mailbox
      a.item Chat
      a.item Contacts
      a.item Photo Editor
      a.item Calendar
      a.item Filter
      a.item Todo

    .title.item
        i.dropdown.icon
        | Layouts
    .content
        a.item Sidebar
        a.item Nav
        a.item Animated Icon
        a.item Box
        a.item Cards
        a.item Colors
        a.item Comment
        a.item Embed
        a.item Faq
        a.item Feed
        a.item Gallery
        a.item Grid
        a.item Header
        a.item Timeline
        a.item Message
        a.item Price

    a.item
      b Components

    .title.item
        i.dropdown.icon
        | UI-Kit

    .content
        a.item Accordion
        a.item Breadcrumb
        a.item Button
        a.item Divider
        a.item Dropdown
        a.item Flag
        a.item Icon
        a.item Image
        a.item Label
        a.item List
        a.item Modal
        a.item Notification
        a.item Alert
        a.item Progress
        a.item Range Semantic
        a.item Range Material
        a.item Rating
        a.item Tab
        a.item Tooltip
        a.item Transition

    .title.item
        i.dropdown.icon
        | Pages
    .content
        a.item Profile
        a.item Settings
        a.item Blank
        a.item Sign In
        a.item Sign Up
        a.item Forgot Password
        a.item Lock Me Screen
        a.item Error 404
        a.item Coming Soon

    .title.item
        i.dropdown.icon
        | Form
    .content
        a.item Form Element
        a.item Input
        a.item Form Validation
        a.item Html Editor

    .title.item
        i.dropdown.icon
        | Tables
    .content
        a.item Static Table
        a.item Datatable
        a.item Editable
    .title.item
      i.dropdown.icon
      | Chart
    .content
      a.item Charts 1
      a.item Charts 2
      a.item Charts 3

    .title.item.openbtn
        i.icon.angle.double.left
        | Collapse Sidebar

  .ui.dropdown.test.item.displaynone
    z Dashboard
    i.icon.demo-icon.heart.icon-heart

    .menu
        .header
            | Dashboard
        .ui.divider
            a.item Dashboard

  .ui.dropdown.test.item.displaynone
    z Layout
    i.icon.demo-icon.world.icon-globe

    .menu
        .header
            | Layout
        .ui.divider
        a.item Inbox
        a.item Mailbox
        a.item Chat
        a.item Contacts
        a.item Photo Editor
        a.item Calendar
        a.item Filter
        a.item Todo

  .ui.dropdown.test.item.displaynone
    z Pages
    i.icon.demo-icon.icon-params.alarm

    .menu
        .header
            | Layouts
        .ui.divider
        a.item Sidebar
        a.item Nav
        a.item Animated Icon
        a.item Box
        a.item Cards
        a.item Colors
        a.item Comment
        a.item Embed
        a.item Faq
        a.item Feed
        a.item Gallery
        a.item Grid
        a.item Header
        a.item Timeline
        a.item Message
        a.item Price

  .ui.dropdown.item.openbtn.displaynone
    z Toggle
    i.icon.demo-icon.icon-params.angle.double.right

.pusher
  header#logged-in.ui.fixed.top.inverted.menu.borderless
    = link_to image_tag('catch-all-white.png', size: '200x50', class: "ui image"), root_path, class: 'header item'
    a.item Dashboard

    .right.menu
        -if current_user
            = link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'item'
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {  
  $('.ui.search.dropdown').dropdown({
    clearable: true
  });
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  $(".openbtn").on("click", function() {
    $(".ui.sidebar").toggleClass("very thin icon");
    $(".sidebar z").toggleClass("displaynone");
    $(".ui.accordion").toggleClass("displaynone");
    $(".ui.dropdown.item").toggleClass("displayblock");

    $(".logo").find('img').toggle();

  });
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  $(".test").dropdown({
    allowCategorySelection: true,
    transition: "fade up",
    context: 'sidebar',
    on: "hover"
  });
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  $('.ui.accordion').accordion({
    selector: {

    }
  });  
});
```

Note: Since I have another dropdown for a search functionality feature, I used the `.test` class for the sidebar dropdown so they won't affect each others' behavior. I was able to verify via inspect element that when I hover on my sidebar icons, the menu items get loaded but they don't appear as expected similar to the codepen example above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to hover by wrapping the js code in `$(document).ready(() => { code }` and removing `context: 'sidebar'`, at the end I dropped even the `allowCategorySelection: true` so it looked like this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
   $(".test").dropdown({
      transition: "fade up",
      on: "hover"
  });
});
```